# Make laravel's unit tests to execute code inside AppServiceProvider::boot

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Inside my `AppServiceProvider::boot` I am adding some methods to Laravel's `Collection` class. Then I am writting UnitTests to test these functionality, and execute these unit tests with `./artisan test MyTest`

I have found that what laravel `test` command does is actually calls to `vendor/bin/phpunit MyTest` which doesn't load Laravel's service providers.

So the question is how do I make AppServiceProvider to be loaded when running unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./vendor/bin/phpunit` calls all tests defined inside your `phpunit.xml -> <testsuites>`, your issue could be that you are using `\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` as your `TestCase`, in that case you are **NOT** loading the framework, so you just either use `Test\TestCase` or move your test to `Feature` and **USE** `Test\TestCase`